# Ajuda com chave estrangeira

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema de intranet onde o usuário cria um recado para diferente setores da empresa, apos criar o recado, ele pode ser editado e quando ele sofre uma alteração, ele coloca um hiperlink editado no fim do recado, que  ao ser clicado, abre uma modal com o recado original.

Ate ai tudo bem, o problema é quando um recado sofre mais de uma alteração, meu `select` pega sempre o primeiro registro, ao invés de pegar todos. Vou tentar descrever como funciona:

TABELA RECADOS tem (id, recado, data, hora) e etc. TABELA RECADOS_EDITADOS tem (id, id_recados <- chave estrangeira de recados.) etc

EXEMPLO:

Faco um `INSERT` na tabela **RECADOS** ela recebe o id=31. Se eu modificar esse recado, ocorre um `UPDATE` na tabela **RECADOS** e um `INSERT` na tabela **RECADOS_EDITADO**, que recebe um id dele e o id_recados=31, que seria a chave estrangeira. 
       Se eu fizer outro `UPDATE` na tabela **RECADOS**, a tabela  **RECADOS_EDITADO** sofre outro `INSERT` com a mesma chave estrangeira 31.

Ai quando eu faco um `select` por exemplo `SELECT * FROM RECADOS_EDITADOS WHERE id_recados = 31`, ele pega o primeiro registro com 31 e não todos.

Ja tentei fazer isso e não resolveu:

```
  $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recadosedit WHERE idRecados = '$id'");
    $v = mysql_fetch_array($select);


    $linhas = mysql_num_rows($select);

    $recadoAnterior = array();
    $dtAlterado = array();
    $hrAlterado = array();


    for($i = 0 ; $i <= $linhas ; $i++){
    $recadoAnterior[$i] = $v['recado'];
    $dtAlterado[$i] = $v['dtAlterado'];
    $hrAlterado[$i] = $v['hrAlterado'];
    }
```

Na hora de exibir eu também faco um for, mas ele sempre mostra o mesmo registro.

```
 for($i = 0 ; $i <= $linhas ; $i++){echo '

       <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns">
    <label>'.$recadoAnterior[$i].'</label>
    <label>Data alterado:</label>'.$dtAlterado[$i].' <label>Hora alterado:</label>'.$hrAlterado[$i].'


    </div>
      </div>';
      }
```

Comment: Wesley, Tenta quebrar o seu problema em partes, primeiro você tem que identificar se tudo esta ok no seu banco de dados, vai nele e faz um select * from RECADOS_EDITADOS WHERE id_recados = 31 se la retornar apenas um registro voce tem que verificar o por que de estar fazendo update no mesmo registro, se ele esta respeitando o primary key se este id  e autoincrement

Comment: Certo, eu fiz isso e ele trouxe 4 registros e no meu código acredito que ele esta pegando esses 4 registro porque no select se eu colocar ORDER BY id DESC ele traz um registro, se eu trocar o DESC por ASC, ele traz outro, então acredito que ele esta pegando todos, só não consigo mostrar todos para o usuário

Comment: esse $v esta pegando todos os registros ? não deveria ser com ele o mysql_num_rows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça o seguinte:

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM recadosedit WHERE idRecados = {$id}";
    if($query = mysql_query($select)){
        if(mysql_num_rows($select)){
            while($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
                $resultados[] = $resultado; 
            }   
        }   
    }

    if(!empty($resultado)){
        foreach($resultados as $resultado){
            print " Recado: " . $resultado['recado'];
            print " Alterado(data): " . $resultado['dtAlterado']    
            print " Alterado(horas): " . $resultado['hrAlterado']   . "<br/>";
        }   
    }
```

Bom, não tenho muito tempo, por isso serei simples e objectivo.

O problema está na forma como retornas os valores dessa consulta com o `mysql_fetch_array`:

```
$v = mysql_fetch_array($select);
```

No caso, armazenas apenas o valor da primeira coluna dos resultados encontrados nessa consulta. Para isso, bastava que introduzisses o `mysql_fetch_array` num loop, como no exemplo acima:

```
while($v = mysql_fetch_array($select))
{
...
}
```

> **[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)**

Comment: Edilson,  agradeco pela grande ajuda, seu codigo deu certo, so precisei trocar o if(!empty($resultado)) por if(!empty($resultados)).

Comment: Mas, quando eu clico no primeiro recado editado ele mostra todas alteração, quando clico no segundo ele mostra todas as alterações do primeiro e do segundo.

Comment: Olha, talvez tenha compreendido mal o problema, podes explicar-te melhor ?

Comment: Seguinte, tem uma pagina de recados, nessa pagina ele faz um select para buscar todos recados que estão em aberto, e uso o while para mostrar o recado, dentro desse while tem um If para verificar se esse recado ja foi editado, caso ele ja tenha sido editado ele mostra o recado e  um hiperlink escrito editado, onde o usuário  clica no editado e aparece o recado anterior em um modal, onde entra o código que você me ajudou, que por sinal deu certo, o único problema que se eu clicar no recado abaixo, ele mostra as edição dele e dos recados que estão acima.

Comment: Coloquei isso no fim do for: unset($resultados); e resolveu, agradeço pela ajuda Edilson

Comment: Talvez porque estavas a reutilizar essa mesma variável.